# Graph coloring problem redundant constraints

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, graphs

Say the edges of a 4 nodes graph are `0 1`, `1 2` and `1 3`.

The solution to the colouring problem can be `1,0,1,1` or `0,1,0,0`, both are essentially the same. How I can model redundant constraints for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Search for symmetry breaking constraints. Here's a small but common example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415333/assymetric-graph-coloring-formulation
2. Fix some variables. E.g. Greedily find the largest clique in your graph, and hard code the colors of the vertices in this clique.